# Roll up sparse date ranges in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that looks like this:

```
date         id  value
2017-01-01   1   1
2017-01-01   2   1
2017-01-02   1   3
2017-01-03   1   6
2017-02-15   1   1
2017-02-17   1   5
2017-02-18   1   8
2017-02-19   1   3
```

I would like to roll it up as follows: For each date, roll up all rows that fall in the next two weeks and sum the values. There are no overlaps in the dataset, the spacing of the groups of dates is quite sparse.

For the above sample, the result would be:

```
date         id value
2017-01-01   1  9
2017-01-01   2  1
2017-02-15   1  17
```

How can I do this in a pandas dataframe?

I've tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='14d', axis=1))['value'].sum().reset_index()
```

This uses a fixed rolling window of 2 weeks, whereas I want to always start on the first day with data. This method can split batches in two if the window boundary falls in the middle. Also, I can't work out how to combine the Grouper date grouping with normal grouping so that the `key` column is taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your desired result it looks like you want the values summed up for the first or second half of the month.

```
import pandas as pd
```

create sample

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "date": [
        "2017-01-01", "2017-01-01", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-03",
        "2017-02-15", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-18", "2017-02-19",
    ],
    "id": [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    "value": [1, 1, 3, 6, 1, 5, 8, 3],
})
```

round days down to 1 or 15

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"]).apply(
    lambda x: x.replace(day=1) if x.day < 15 else x.replace(day=15)
)
```

groupby.sum for date and id

```
df.groupby(["date", "id"]).value.sum().reset_index()
```